# gradle bootRun works and java -jar does not

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven, gradle

I've a "spring boot app" application.

I'm executing my software with "gradle bootRun" and It works correctly for all developers.

To make the jar or war I've used maven and currently I'm using gradle.

With both methods to generated jar or war the execution of software from this artifacts isn't working propertly in one of hundreds of use cases.

The error is:

```
Error: Error while starting plugin CheckGebaeudeVersicherungsSystemIoxPlugin
Error:   ch/interlis/iox_j/validator/InterlisFunction
Error:     ch.interlis.iox_j.validator.InterlisFunction
Error: Error while starting plugin  org.interlis2.validator.plugins.IntersectsIoxPlugin
Error:   ch/interlis/iox_j/validator/InterlisFunction
Error:     ch.interlis.iox_j.validator.InterlisFunction
Error: Error while starting plugin org.interlis2.validator.plugins.no_overlaps_2_1_6_IoxPlugin
Error:   ch/interlis/iox_j/validator/InterlisFunction
Error:     ch.interlis.iox_j.validator.InterlisFunction
Error: Error while starting plugin org.interlis2.validator.plugins.no_overlaps_2_2_0_IoxPlugin
Error:   ch/interlis/iox_j/validator/InterlisFunction
Error:     ch.interlis.iox_j.validator.InterlisFunction
```

This seems to be an error of a missing dependency.

This error is not because of something on the code. In eclipse with execution and debug, all is working properly!

What's the difference in execute between "gradle bootRun"/"mvn spring-boot:run" and the execution with java commad (traditional "java -jar jar/war")?

Comment: Had similar issue, but mine was solved in an unexpected way - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49136431/project-running-with-bootrun-but-not-with-java-jar/49137464#49137464