# Project running with bootRun but not with java -jar

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, mybatis

Have a similar question to [gradle bootRun works and java -jar does not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47446281/gradle-bootrun-works-and-java-jar-does-not)

I build my project with `./gradlew bootRun`

My project works when I run it with `./gradlew bootRun` but not with `java -jar build/libs/my_application.jar` it gives me the following error:

```
org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Invalid bound statement (not found): com.example.dao.UserDao.insert
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod$SqlCommand.<init>(MapperMethod.java:230) ~[mybatis-3.4.2.jar!/:3.4.2]
    ...
```

What's the difference here? Why wouldn't it run with the jar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was solved with having the `mybatis` `XML` file name with uppercase letter. But it still isn't clear why `bootRun` is able to find it with lowercase letter and `java -jar` isn't.

Comment: Most likely because the file was read from the filesystem in `bootRun`, which must be case insensitive, while inside the jar, names are case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

Given your follow up comment, the most likely explanation is that `bootRun` reads the file from a *case insensitive* file system. And on the other hand the locating files inside the jar is case sensitive.